# NodeJS flush function streams not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, pipe

I have this main file, with the goal to output the sum of profits for a country

```
const { createReadStream } = require("fs");
const parse = require("csv-parse");
const csv = require("csvtojson");
const { filterByCountry } = require("./filter-by-country");
const { sumProfit } = require("./sum-profit.js");

const csvParser = csv();

createReadStream("data.csv") // (1)
  .pipe(csvParser) // (2)
  .pipe(filterByCountry("Italy"))
  .pipe(sumProfit())
  .pipe(process.stdout);
```

csvparser works, filterByCountry works but once it goes through sumProfit() I am unable to output just 1 **TOTAL** for the profit.

sumProfit function:

```
const { Transform } = require("stream");
const { EOL } = require("os");
let TOTAL = 0;

const sumProfit = () => {
  return new Transform({
    objectMode: true,
    transform: (chunk, encoding, done) => {
      const parsedObj = JSON.parse(chunk);
      TOTAL += Math.floor(parseFloat(parsedObj["profit"]));
      done(null);
    },
    //flush function ??
    function(done) {
      done(null, String(TOTAL) + EOL);
    },
  });
};

module.exports = { sumProfit };
```

If I remove the *flush* function I have tried to implement and replace the done(null) with done(null, String(TOTAL)) It logs everytime the total is added...

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, Fixed the sumProfit functions to:

```
const { Transform } = require("stream");
const { EOL } = require("os");

let TOTAL = 0;

const sumProfit = () => {
  return new Transform({
    objectMode: true,
    transform: (chunk, encoding, done) => {
      const parsedObj = JSON.parse(chunk);
      TOTAL += Math.floor(parseFloat(parsedObj["profit"]));
      done(null);
    },
    flush: (done) => {
      done(null, String(TOTAL) + EOL);
    },
  });
};

module.exports = { sumProfit };
```

Silly mistake I am used to using through2